# How to properly pass a string to page.evaluate()?

Tags: puppeteer

Hi I am working on a web scraping script, and I have a function that currently returns to me a string. I want to pass the result of that function into page.evaluate. It is returning undefined - which according to the docs I think is for a good reason (non-serializable).

How would I go about this function?

```
    let imgTag = await comparer(img1, productImageURLarr); ///returns String

    let divSel = imgTag

    let parentdivs = await page.evaluate(
        (divSel) => {[...document.querySelectorAll(`img[alt=${divSel}]`)].map(elem => elem.closest('href'))
        }, divSel);

    console.log(parentdivs) ///returns undefined
```

also noted - when I put in the value of the string (not surrounded by quotes) instead of the expression it returns the object I want.

Comment: It looks like your function isn't returning anything. Did you try `return [...].map(...)`

Comment: Lol- you were right. Exactly the issue. return worked.. Before I put the curly braces I was using an implicit return :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `return` keyword in the `parentdivs` function.

```
    let parentdivs = await page.evaluate(divSel => {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(`img[alt=${divSel}]`)].map(elem => elem.closest('href'))
    }, divSel);
```